# Genfromtxt throw exceptions "got 3 columns instead of 27" bu it is not so

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, genfromtxt

I use:

```
Data = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter='"\t"', dtype=None, autostrip=True, skip_header=1)
```

And in proccess it gives me raise ValueError(errmsg)

```
Line #33 (got 3 columns instead of 27)
```

But it is not so. In file in that line I have all columns! I checked - function read those lines with "missing values" untill some symbol:
For example, in line 33 function read this:

```
"http://www.savvyeat.com/whole-wheat-chocolate-chai-muffins/"   "2152"  "{""title"":""Whole Wheat Chocolate Chai Muffins Savvy Eats "",""body"":""I think I subconsciously sabotaged myself Two weeks ago I couldn t
```

How can I read my file in numpy array in other way or somehow fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show the data file?

Comment: Line 33 looks incomplete. There are unmatched quotation marks. Does the column really end with `I couldn t`?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you intend to use `'"\t"'` as your delimiter ? It's a bit unusual.

Comment: Line 33 is incomplete, because function read her until that symbols. File is here http://rghost.ru/48493970 Need press button "Скачать" :-))  .

Comment: Yes, with delimeter '"\t"' for usual line it works fine. But for some lines function doesn't work(about 300 line in 7300 line file)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem should be quickly solvable once we can see the contents of the CSV file. To debug the problem run:

```
import itertools as IT
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    content = ''.join(IT.islice(f, 50))
    print(repr(content))
```

and post the output.  That will give us the first 50 lines of the file. If there is sensitive data, you can redact it before posting; just leave the quotation marks and `\t` intact.

Comment: Piece of one sentention: "the uk's #1 news portal", with your code it reads fine, but with getfromtxt fall before "#1". I delete sign # and left with "the uk's 1 news portal", and now genfromtxt read it all.